# Firefox browse does not play my .mp3 files in jquery when click a button in firefox?

Tags: jquery, firefox, audio

i trying to play a sound file when i click the button, but it's not working in Firefox but its works great in chrome, my html code is :

`<html> <body> <div id="container">

            <button id="play">Play Music</button>
        </div> 
    </body> 
</html>`

My Scripting:

`$(document).ready(function() {`

`var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
                audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'Bullet.mp3');`

`$('#play').click(function() {`
`audioElement.play();
                });
            });`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Firefox does not play MP3 audio because of licensing issues. See: http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio

Comment: @techfoobar:ok but i have to play mp3 files in firefox how it is possible

Comment: You need .ogg files for firefox and chrome.